# a file addition by an incomplete (file) name

Tags: java, android, file

I have a method:

```
public void setup () {
File file = new File(74761_control_*.xml)
//some code
}
```

Where * - **variable part**. Not known in advance how it will exactly be called a file. The program is required to load an xml file with the same name. Is there an elegant way to do this with a standard Java SE API?

Comment: There is no guarantee that your pattern does not match multiple files. So no, this does not work.

Comment: @isnot2bad I guarantee that this pattern will have only one file.

Comment: Yes, you guarantee for yourself, but as you can't guarantee for the rest of the world, there is no direct java API that allows you to use a pattern to construct a `File` object, as a `File` object always references one single file or directory. But see my answer below, there is another, not much more complex way to do what you want.

Comment: Plenty of resources if you google for *java open file wildcard*

Answer (score 0):

The `java.nio` package has some convencience methods to iterate over directories using a file name pattern:

```
Path dir = Paths.get("c:\\temp");
Iterator<Path> iterator = Files.newDirectoryStream(dir,  
                                    "74761_control_*.xml").iterator();
```

Now, iterator "holds" all paths that fit to the glob pattern above.
The rest is iterator/file handling:

```
if (!iterator.hasNext()) {
    // file not found
} else {
    Path path = iterator.next();
    // process file, e.g. read all data
    Files.readAllBytes(path);
    // or open a reader
    try (BufferedReader reader = Files.newBufferedReader(path)) {
        // process reader
    }

    if (iterator.hasNext()) {
        // more than one file found
    }
}
```